# Xcode 6.3 Apple Match-O linker Error with cocos2d v2.1.5 project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-x

I got a problem when I rebuild `cocos2d v2.1.5` with architecture x64 in xcode 6.3. please help me fix this.

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_WebPGetFeaturesInternal", referenced from:
      WebPGetFeatures(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, WebPBitstreamFeatures*) in CCImageCommonWebp.o
  "_WebPInitDecoderConfigInternal", referenced from:
      WebPInitDecoderConfig(WebPDecoderConfig*) in CCImageCommonWebp.o
  "_WebPDecode", referenced from:
      cocos2d::CCImage::_initWithWebpData(void*, int) in CCImageCommonWebp.o
  "_NEON_Matrix4Mul", referenced from:
      _kmMat4Multiply in mat4.o
  "_AES_decrypt", referenced from:
      DataEncrypt::parseXMLData(unsigned long, char const*) in UserDataEncrypt.o
  "_AES_set_encrypt_key", referenced from:
      DataEncrypt::save() in UserDataEncrypt.o
  "_AES_encrypt", referenced from:
      DataEncrypt::save() in UserDataEncrypt.o
  "_AES_set_decrypt_key", referenced from:
      DataEncrypt::parseXMLData(unsigned long, char const*) in UserDataEncrypt.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update cocos2d to version 2.2.6. It's minimum version which supports x64 architecture. However it's not stable, so you'd better update to 3.6 if you have enough time.

[Link to tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/03/migrating-cocos2diphone-v3-tips-tricks/)

We've started migration and it looks like it will take 80+ hours because of big changes in API.

Comment: i'm newbie, how can i upgrade to 3.6. do you have a tutorial for this problem.

Comment: We've updated to 2.2.6 very quickly without any changes to code, compiled successfully, but got bunch of runtime memory-related errors and decided to migrate to 3.6.

Comment: i've updated 2.2.6 but it still get the same error. you know why? `

Comment: verify that dependent project has support for this architecture. and try to build for device not for simulator

Comment: yeah...i fixed it.. and i still dont know why i added x86_64 architecture on xcode but still get that error..Everything is oke on my device